# What is the best way to allow a domain user to start and stop services on the machine?

Tags: security, active-directory, permissions, windows-service

What is the best way to allow a domain user to start and stop services on the machine? The domains user cannot be made admin.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/342677/6079

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349

Answer (score 0):

Can you get away with making them "Power Users"?