# PowerShell automated service failure "Run a Program" recovery, "nt authority\local service" permission issue

Tags: windows, powershell, service, windows-service

I have written a simple powershell script to trigger an email notification and restart a service when a service failure occurs, and have been testing it on my desktop by crashing the Windows Audio server ("Audiosrv").

The script is set up to run by going into Services -> right click on service -> Properties -> Recovery -> First/Second/Subsequent Failures -> Run A Program, with the program parameters listed below.

The Local Service account (NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE) runs this script on the service failure, this is known by the whoami command output during the script. This account can use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet (I receive the email), but it cannot use the Restart-Service cmdlet (or Start-Service, or net start, or sc start?). See the error message, this is the same error message received when trying to run Restart-Service as a user without admin privilege.

How can I temporarily elevate privileges so that this script can restart the service? Or what should I do differently?

Run Program:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Command Line Parameters:

```
-File C:\Scripts\StoppedServiceNotifyEmail.ps1
```

Powershell script (emails/hostnames redacted):

```
$serviceName = "Audiosrv"
$serviceDisplayName = "Windows Audio"
$fromAddress = "xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.org"
$toAddress = "xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.org"

$initialFailedBody=@"
<head>
   <style type='text/css'>
       body {
           font-family: Calibri;
           font-size: 11pt;
           color: black;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>$serviceDisplayName ($serviceName) on $env:computername has failed, attempting to restart the service.</p>
</body>
"@

whoami | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\whoami_after_Audiosrv_fail.txt
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer xxxxxxxxxxxxx -Port xxx -from $fromAddress -to $toAddress -subject "$serviceDisplayName ($serviceName) failed on $env:computername" -body $initialFailedBody -BodyAsHTML -priority High
Start-Sleep -s 10
Restart-Service -Name $serviceName
```

Powershell error output:

```
Restart-Service : Service 'Windows Audio (Audiosrv)' cannot be stopped due to the following
error: Cannot open Audiosrv service on computer '.'.
At C:\Util\StoppedServiceNotifyEmail.ps1:82 char:5
+     Restart-Service -Name $serviceName
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceControl
   ler) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCom
   mand
```

Comment: You can install this custom [PowerShellAccessControl Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83), and then run this powershell command first with admin rights to grant the service account `nt authority\local serice` rights to manage Windows Audio Service using `Get-Service Audiosrv | Add-AccessControlEntry -ServiceAccessRights Start,Stop -Principal NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`, BTW, there are simpler methods available along the same lines.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks for your help! Yes this works for me. Do you have a simple way to edit the service access right in Windows without the extra powershell module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grant start/stop/restart permissions on a service to an arbitrary user or group on a non-domain-member server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user; please try the solutions in the linked question.