# Allow user/group to start/stop/restart windows service

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019, windows-service, user-permissions

I have 4 services. All of them are run by an individual user. All 4 users are part of a group I created (ServiceWorkers) which has the `Log on as a service` user rights assigned. Each service needs to restart now and then. The problem is, that the user rights assignment seems not to have sufficient permission to start/stop/restart the service.

What is the correct way to grant a group permission to start/stop/restart services?
It doesn't matter in my case that it's 4 different users and 4 different services. When the group is able to just start/stop/restart (all) services it would be fine for now.

I found some setups but they are either extremely old, tools are no longer available (subinacl), or seem to revolve around giving permissions to a service. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: It is possible with sc.exe. Check the article - http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/

Comment: Or this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/187691/536173