# How do you give an account permission to a start and stop a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-service

How can I give an account permission to start or stop a particular Windows Service using SC.exe?

What I'm trying to do is from one machine A call these operations from another machine B:

```
net.exe use \\B /delete
net.exe use \\B /user:B\<username> <password>
sc.exe \\B stop <service name>
```

The issue is that the first two operations pass but the third one fails.

Comment: Duplicate of the vaguely titled question http://serverfault.com/questions/7979/starting-and-stopping-services

Comment: I've made the other post's title more descriptive, but I prefer the title of this post.

Comment: More duplicate/similar posts: http://serverfault.com/q/187302/6079 , http://serverfault.com/q/166641/6079 , http://serverfault.com/q/15147/6079 And I see each of those have more linked (similar) questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give your user the permission to stop the service either explicitly or via the membership of a sufficiently privileged group. This can be done by first changing a security template using the [Security Templates MMC snapin](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_scetopnode.mspx?mfr=true) and subsequently applying it to your system either [locally](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_scetopnode.mspx?mfr=true) or [via group policy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_scetopnode.mspx?mfr=true). This works at least [on from Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_permissions.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: The pre-built Security Template MMC is secpol.msc.

Comment: Linked pages "locally" and "via group policy" no longer work.